# Insignificant p-value

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I've a question regarding insignificant p-value.

If I got p-value greater than 0.05, does that mean my result is biological insignificant?

Can anyone help me to clear this up?

Comment: I think your question is related to the [meaning of p-value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). If you still don't understand after reading this you can ask specific questions =)

Comment: $p$-values tell you nothing about biological significance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are testing $H_0: \mu = 100$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 100,$ where
the value of $\mu$ may be of importance in biology.

If the p-value of a test exceeds 5%, then there is not sufficient evidence to reject $H_0.$ Then you would say there is not evidence of a statistically significant change in $\mu$ (from 100) according to the data used for the test.

Even if the p-value is smaller than 5% and you can claim a *statistically significant* change, that does not mean that the effect is of *practical importance* in biology,  That is for an biologist to say. (I think this is
an example of what @EricWong says in his Comment.)

Maybe you have a huge amount of data and you can claim $\mu \approx 100.5$ instead of $\mu = 100.$  The change by 0.5 might be 'real', but a biologist
might say that's not an important difference. (She might say, "I'd be really
interested if you told me the change is **5**, but people would laugh if I
wrote a paper claiming a difference of 0.5.")

If a study is wisely planned with about the right number $n$ of observations,
then statistical significance and practical importance will amount to about
the same thing. That takes more careful advance planning than one often
sees in practice.